# calculating mean squared prediction error based on simulated data in R

Tags: r, simulation, lapply, lm

I have following data. My goal is to calculate mean squared prediction error (MSPE)using cross validation by replicating 100 times.

```
y=rnorm(250,0,2)
    x1=rnorm(250,0,3)
    x2=rnorm(250,1,1)
    datasim=data.frame(y,x1,x2)
```

From this first i need to split the data in to training and test data. So i first calculated the indices using sample.int function in R. Based on those indices i split the data into training and test set.

```
    dd=replicate(100,sample.int(n = nrow(datasim), 
size = floor(.75*nrow(datasim)), replace = F))

          train_set=apply(dd,2,function(y)
          datasim[y, ])

        test_set=apply(dd,2,function(y)
          datasim[-y, ])
```

After that i have to use the training data to fit the model. And based on test data , i need to predict and obtain mean squared prediction error (MSPE). I don't know how to proceed from here. Especially i dont know how to link the training set and test set so that i can predict and calculate MSPE.

I tried it using this using a lapply function which is inside of another lapply function.

```
lapply(test_set, function(train_set) {
  lapply(train_set,function(x)
    mean((test_set$y- predict.lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = train_set))^2)

}
  ))
```

But there seems to be a problem with this.Can anyone help me to figure out this ? Also is there any easier method to do this than this method ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To `replicate` remember that you need to pass a function.

This is something to get you going, also you should `predict` on test data, use `newdata` in the call to `predict`.

First, this function does all the part about splitting data and the model, notice that you can pass different `perc`, if you want to change that later.

```
sim_function <- function(datas, perc=0.75) {
  idx = sample(nrow(datas), floor(perc*nrow(datas)), replace = F) # sample idx

  train = datas[idx, ]
  test = datas[-idx, ]

  pred_lm = predict(lm(y~x1+x2,data=train), # model on train data
              newdata = test[, -1]) # predict on test data

  return(mean((test$y - pred_lm)^2)) # mse and return it
}
```

Now we can call `replicate`:

```
sim_rep <- replicate(100, sim_function(datasim)) # or sim_function(datasim, perc = 0.60) as an example
head(sim_rep)
[1] 4.664940 3.543390 3.119503 3.493320 4.182965 5.101870
```

Data:

```
set.seed(123) # always remember this when you simulate
y=rnorm(250,0,2)
x1=rnorm(250,0,3)
x2=rnorm(250,1,1)
datasim=data.frame(y,x1,x2)
```